# Should I make authentication as a separate service in a microservice architecture? What should it do?

Tags: .net, authentication, architecture, microservices, openid

I am trying to figure out whether I should abstract authentication as a separate service in my application. Given that it is a good idea to have it as a standalone microservice, what should it do exactly? My initial thought process is to have it issue out JWT tokens and validate them when needed, but wouldn't this lead to me duplicating the same authentication code in every single application? I am also quite new to the concept of OpenID Connect and even after reading through the documentation, it is still a bit unclear.

This is what I think my microservice should have:

```
 public string CreateToken(User user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
            //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Anonymous")

        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            _config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
            signingCredentials: cred);

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        
        return jwt;
    }

    public bool ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = 
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"])),
            ValidIssuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        return true;
    }
```

Lastly, if I do end up abstracting this into a separate microservice, how would the calling look like from another microservice? Thank you for the time and I apologize for the load of questions, just want to make sure I understand it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to always place the service that issues and manages tokens in its own service. Otherwise you will have a much harder time reasoning about the system, who is doing what and troubleshooting.

I highly recommend using [IdentityServer](https://duendesoftware.com/) to manage the tokens for you.